# How to add index of each element in jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, jbuilder

In my Rails application I do the following to export all my data as a JSON string with jbuilder:

**index.json.jbuilder**

```
json.array!(@react_exp) do |exp|
  json.id(**INDEX HERE**)
  json.createdAt((exp.created_at.to_f * 1000).to_i) 
  json.updatedAt((exp.updated_at.to_f * 1000).to_i) 
  json.extract! exp, :description
  json.categoryId(exp.category_id)
  json.extract! exp, :value
  json.day(exp.day.strftime('%Q').to_i)
end
```

This works fine so far. What I want is to add the index of each element where it say **INDEX HERE** (as an ID for the resulting object).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no out of the box way, but you can use Ruby [`each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) method.

```
json.array! @react_exp.each_with_index do |exp, index|
  json.id index
  json.createdAt((exp.created_at.to_f * 1000).to_i) 
  json.updatedAt((exp.updated_at.to_f * 1000).to_i) 
  json.extract! exp, :description
  json.categoryId(exp.category_id)
  json.extract! exp, :value
  json.day(exp.day.strftime('%Q').to_i)
end
```

Read this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/issues/270).

Comment: Question: Why do you want `index` instead  of `id`?

Comment: I have to import these data into a firebase database and during import in firebase it sets a key for each object which is basically the index of each element. In order for my React application that I'm developing to work correctly I need each key as id in my object. This approach seems to me the most straightforward.

Comment: @Oliver Oh I see. But as far as I know Firebase creates Key for each record,

Comment: You can even out the `#to_a` since the methods expect something to iterate over, not specifically an array.

Comment: Furthermore, I believe the first level of array destruction can also be omitted. The first level of array destruction is automatically done by Ruby when each element is an array. Thus `|(exp, index)|` could just be `|exp, index|`.